# Replacing all values higher than X with NA, in only one column

Tags: r, na

I have one column in my dataframe with extreme outliers which I would like to replace with NA. How do I go about this. Basically I would like to replace all values higher than 30 in a column with NA.

I've tried these codes and none of them worked:

```
replace_with_na_all(DATAt$ColumnName, ~ .x > 30)

na_if(DATA, DATAt$ColumnName>30)

DATA[, 5][DATA[, 5] >30] <- NA
```

Comment: `is.na(DATA[[5]]) <- DATA[[5]] > 30`?

Answer (score 0):

Helpful comment by @Rui Barradas:

`is.na(DATA[[5]]) <- DATA[[5]] > 30`

---

Compilation of why the codes in the question don't work (and their close alternatives):

1. `naniar::replace_with_na_all` takes a *dataframe* as its first argument. Since you want to replace only at one column, `naniar::replace_with_na_at` is what you actually need. Usage:

```
replace_with_na_at(DATA, "ColumnName", ~ .x > 30)
```

2. `dplyr::na_if` accept a *single value*, not a condition, as its second argument.`dplyr` does not provide a single function to replace values meeting a condition to NA. Closest solution of `dplyr`-style:

```
mutate(DATA, ColumnName = case_when(ColumnName > 30 ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ ColumnName))
```

3. The provided base R approach actually should work, just like with the following alternatives:

```
is.na(DATA$ColumnName) <- DATA$ColumnName > 30
```

```
DATA$ColumnName[Data$ColumnName > 30] <- NA
```